# Is there a simple way to copy a repository fragment from CodeCommit to S3?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codecommit

I use a combination of a static code generator and `webpack` to generate a static site, which I then manually copy to S3 (to further expose it though CloudFront) via the AWS cli.

I manage my code with git locally and on a local git server, and was considering a move to CodeCommit to have a complete integration with AWS. The first step would be to synchronize the `dest` folder of my repo with an S3 bucket.

I was hoping for a simple integration ("copy upon a push event") but did not find any. I saw a few discussions on that subject with a [recent blog post](https://stelligent.com/2017/09/05/continuous-delivery-to-s3-via-codepipeline-and-codebuild/) being the closest to what I want to achieve.

It is however a complicated process, involving mysterious setups across three services.

Is there something I missed? A more obvious solution that the answer to a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270656/deploy-files-from-codecommit-to-s3)?

Comment: have you looked into Git FTP? https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp

Comment: @Chad: I am not sure how this is relevant to CodeCommit and S3 synchronization?

Comment: I miss understood - it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional remote on your local repository, and sync/push changes directly to AWS. When you feel the time is right you can stop using either of them. Once you created the AWS CodeCommit you can add the remote as followed:

```
git remote add [REMOTE NAME] https://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/MyDemoRepo
# Set a new remote
git remote -v
# Verify new remote
```

For the second part to upload to S3 your destination folder, what engine are you using for your static website? If its NPM you could you at the following for example; https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-deploy

Once you have it working locally you can go the Stelligent route and integrate it in a pipeline, where you have AWS Build trigger your local build step and push it automatic to your S3 Folder.

Comment: Thank you but my question was focused on the last part - that is how to move from CodeCommit to S3. When you mention "the Stelligent way" -- I guess you meant the blog I liked in my question and which makes this operation very complicated and i am hoping for an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you currently a CodePipeline user?  The simplest way would probably be to set up a pipeline with CodeCommit as a source action (CodePipeline automatically uploads all artifacts to S3, and you can specify the bucket on pipeline creation); however, I don't know if that's as simple a solution as you're hoping to find, since it involves configuring at least one other service.

-Paige@AWS

Comment: Thanks - I do not mind to use another service for that but I had a look at CodePipeline and teh documen,tation is extremely confusing for someone who is just starting. This said, after your answer I will give another try and look at finding the elements you mention (*... automatically uploads all artifacts to S3*, etc.)